# parseDouble of Double class adds extra zero

Tags: java, rounding

```
public static double centsToDollars(Number cents, int precision) {
    return BigDecimal.valueOf(cents.doubleValue() / 100).setScale(precision, RoundingMode.DOWN).doubleValue();
}
```

Code above works completely fine when I want to display cents value in dollars. For example, for 1 cent, it returns 0.01 dollar.

```
assertEquals("$0.01", FormatUtils.centsToDollars(1, 3)) 
assertEquals("$0.012", FormatUtils.centsToDollars(1.2345, 3))
assertEquals("$0.327", FormatUtils.centsToDollars(32.7, 3))
```

But I can't figure out, why `FormatUtils.centsToDollars(0.65, 3)` returns $0.0060. I expect to receive 0.006 instead. What is the latest zero about ?

**Update**

Looks like the root cause of the issue is invocation of `doubleValue()` of `BigDecimal`

```
System.out.println(Double.parseDouble("0.006")); 

System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.006).doubleValue());
```

returns 0.0060 for me

Any clue why this happens ?

Comment: What is the exact code for `FormatUtils.centsToDollars()` ?

Comment: Cant reproduce your error. `System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(new BigDecimal(0.65).doubleValue() / 100).setScale(3, RoundingMode.DOWN).doubleValue());` prints `0.006` in my case. Maybe it depends on Locale? You can also try using `BigDecimal("0.65")` with argument as String.

Comment: Checked it with different locale setting, still getting 0.0060.

Comment: Could you try using `cents.divide(new BigDecimal("100"), 3, RoundingMode.DOWN).doubleValue();` as `centsToDollars` return value?

Comment: If I remove .doubleValue() at the end. This code works completely fine. So looks like the issue with .doubleValue of BigDecimal. But I can't figure out why it adds latest zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> parseDouble of Double class adds extra zero

There is a [bug id:4428022](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4428022) in Java 1.4 to 6 which means it adds an extra zero you don't need.  This happens for values 0.001 to 0.009 only.  Java 7 doesn't have this bug.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
    System.out.println(i / 1000.0);
```

in Java 6 prints

0.0010
0.0020
0.0030
0.0040
0.0050
0.0060
0.0070
0.0080
0.0090

but in Java 7 prints

0.001
0.002
0.003
0.004
0.005
0.006
0.007
0.008
0.009

---

I suspect that 0.65 is actually slightly less in reality. When you divide it by 100 you get something like 0.006499999999999 which when rounded drops to 0.006

I suspect what you wanted was

```
public static String centsToDollars(Number cents, int precision) {
    return "$" + BigDecimal.valueOf(cents.doubleValue())
           .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100))
           .setScale(precision, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
}
```

Try

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(0.65 / 100));
```

This is how I would write it

```
public static String centsToDollars(double cents) {
    double rounded = Math.round(cents * 100) / 1e4;
    return "$" + rounded;
}
```

This assumes two decimal places of cents.

Comment: Actually this is real price (half of the cent). And I want to display this price in dollars like others prices )

Comment: It's not clear to me why you are using BigDecimal, perhaps you could say what your real requirement is.

Comment: I've got prices in database. All of the prices are in cents. It varies from 100-150 cents to 1 cents and even half of the cent. I want to display all prices with 3 number precision. In this case I would like to display $0.006

Comment: Isn't $0.007 or $0.0065 closer?

Comment: It could be $0.007 as well. All I want is 3 digit after the comma. Your first code snippet does not compile, and it' not clear for me, why you call setScale before dividing. Second code snippet will round value to 2 number after the comma, returning 0.0 in my case.

Comment: The reason for converting to BigDecimal before performing the division to ensure that there is no rounding error from the division which can case confusion when you round the result.

Comment: Ok, finally I figure out why it is broken. I tried to divide 2 BigDecimals too before to avoid rounding erros. But it did not help. The problem is invoking of doubleValue() at the end. The invocation adds latest zero for me. Any clue why this happens ?

Comment: @aauser There is a bug in Java 6 so doubles 0.001 to 0.009 are printed with an extra 0.  This doesn't happen in Java 7.

Comment: If there is no workaround, this comment about the bug should be accepted as answer. Current answer is about the proper way of rounding to avoid rounding errors

Comment: @aauser To avoid rounding error with BigDecimal, a) convert to big decimal as soon as possible, don't use the result of a calculation.  b) convert to a string using BigDecimal if you can.

Comment: You're confusing the issue. 'It' in the bug report refers to various *formatting* methods, not to Double.parseDouble(), which doesn't add any zeroes whatsoever,

Answer (score 0):

> parseDouble of Double class adds extra zero

No it doesn't. The methods you are using to *format* the double is doing that. Doubles don't contain trailing decimal zeros. They don't contain decimal anything.